# Why does 'package' keyword in Perl modulino break tests?

Tags: perl, testing, modulino

Let's say there's a simple Perl script testme.pl like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub testme {
        return 1;
}

1;
```

And a test file testme.t like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Test::More;
require_ok('testing.pl');
ok(testme());
done_testing();
```

Running `perl testme.t` seems to work as expected, but both http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=537361 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134624/272387 suggest to add a package line, so I modify the original script to be:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
package My::Testing;

sub testme {
        return 1;
}

1;
```

Now the test fails with:

```
Undefined subroutine &main::testme called at testing.t
```

Why so?

Comment: You need to `use My::Testing;` in your test file.  Then call it as My::Testing::testme().  Otherwise look into perldoc Exporter,

Comment: xxfelixxx: He does _not_ need to `use My::Testing` unless he wants to read in a file named `My/Testing.pm` from a Perl library directory found in `@INC`. His code is in a file named `testme.pl`, so `use` won't work with it, and he's already loaded it with `require` (well, `require_ok`), so its contents are already accessible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It fails because your `testme` sub is no longer in the default `main` namespace, it is now in the `My::Testing` namespace (package).  You now need to access it by its full name, `My::Testing::testme()`.

Identifiers in `main` don't need their package to be specified explicitly, since it's the default, but that's why the error message refers to it as `main::testme`.

(You could also `use Exporter` within the `My::Testing` package, export the sub, and then `import` it from your test script as a way of copying the sub into the test script's namespace.  Or you could put another `package My::Testing` command into the test script, so that it will look in the `My::Testing` namespace by default.  But referencing it as `My::Testing::testme()` is the simplest way to fix it and most clearly illustrates the reasoning behind the error message you're getting.)